# Full popup display on hover

Tags: jquery, css, popup, hover

I make a popup div which will shown on hover on another image. popup div is shown using like

```
div.image-normal{//image is in this div
height:315px;
}
img:hover div.popup{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:-315px;
  height:328px;
}
```

I have 12 image in 3 row. Sometime div.popup is cut-off from top browser area when I scrolling. I want that when popup shown and cut-off it will auto scroll and fit in browser window. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Change your position of the popup. This will center it in the middle of the screen.

```
img:hover div.popup {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    height:328px;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/qL5dq/)

Comment: Thanks but I have 12 image in 3 row. Each image had popup. when scrolling page in broswer popup cuts off.

Comment: @user3639684 Your using `absolute` positioning. What do you expect? You will have to create a JSFiddle and show us what you mean because I don't get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want your box to show all the time, even when scrolling?

If so, you'll need to use `position: fixed`.

I created a small simple hover effect on images, you can hover over the diffrent images, and see what image number that is being shown.

This should work for what you are trying to accomplish

http://jsfiddle.net/TMjeb/2/